# how to use compiled OpenSSL in Android for AES encryption

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, openssl, aes

I've to encrypt mp3 audio file using AES 256. When I used Java based encryption, it was quite slow; it was taking around 35 seconds for 6 MB mp3 audio file. Then I was suggested to use JNI and implement encryption in C.

Now I've compiled OpenSSL and have executed 'HEllo world' using JNI. I don't know much about JNI. Can anybody guide me on how to use compiled OpenSSL in Android, and how to implement AES 256 encryption in C and call it from Java?

Comment: I would assume that the Java guys have implemented their encryption already in C/C++ (and perhaps even parts in assembly).  So I'd suggest you check this first.  Also, there might be things you could optimize in your Java code.  Bottom line: Have a good look before replacing the Java libraries.

Comment: Yes I've already mentioned that they're quite slow. If you know any such implementation which is fast, please let me know

Comment: Note: you could have edited [your previous question on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357673/mp3-audio-encryption-decryption-slow-on-android) rather than starting a new one. Questions can come off "on hold" if they are improved.

Comment: yes, but that was not being answered. And after searching  a lot, I came to know JNI can give me good results. So it's good to start a new topic since the previous topic is different altogether

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Write a simple C function that does what you need using the OpenSSL APIs.
2. Make sure it works
3. Create a Java class with a native method that has the necessary input and output. Probably `byte[]` for both.
4. Use `javap` to create a header file form the class in 3.
5. Implement the functions in the header file and call 1. to do the actual work.
6. Read up on JNI for details :)